# How can I get cookies that were set in javascript from a twig template? [NEW]

Tags: craft3, javascript, cookies

This question was already asked a few years ago, and the way of doing it was through a plugin. I was wondering if there is a way of doing it just using Craft and Twig.

I set up a cookie using JavaScript, and I want to read it with Craft. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is for Craft 3, you can do something like this from a template to loop through all available cookies for a site:

```
{% set cookies = craft.app.request.getCookies() %}

{% for cookie in cookies %}
    {{ cookie.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That seems to work, but I get back 'CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN'. I am expecting another value. {% set cookies = craft.app.request.getCookies('invited') %} I'm requesting the cookie like that.

Comment: @JSosa getCookies() returns the collection of cookies. The cookie you want would be cookies['invited'] out of the returned set. Reference: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request#getCookies()-detail

Answer (score 2):

If you want a specific cookie instead of the set of cookies, you'd use

Old Craft 3 Syntax:

```
{% set specificCookie = craft.app.request.getCookie('specificCookie') %}
```

Deprecation Replacement (for Craft 4 compatibility):

```
craft.app.request.cookies.get('specificCookie')
```

Craft 3 Docs: https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-web-twig-variables-request.html#method-getcookie

Codebase Reference: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/v3/src/web/twig/variables/Request.php#L212-L217